# Can i modify a model testing with protractor?

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocking, protractor

I have just started to test with Protractor and I would like to know if I can change a view model from Protractor.

I suppose I can not (without using mocks), because there is little information about it, but i need to do it or try to simulate it.

I have a ng-repeat in my app, if it has results a big panel will be displayed. The model of this ng-repeat is filled with a backend call that i want to avoid (to isolate UI tests).

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Yes, you can mock the call and return dummy data.

Comment: @mikey even the backend call is in other module of my project? i have been trying with httpbackend but no way i can get it working

Comment: Refer http://www.dev9.com/article/2015/1/protractor-using-the-page-object-model